# number of vowels in multiple strings in c++.input as many strings with the stop word "end", the output has to be the number of vowels in each string

Tags: c++

How can i change the code to give the desired output. mine gives the sum of all the vowels in all the strings, instead of the number of vowels in each string in a new line?

please see my code below:

my code outputs the sum of all the vowels in all the strings, instead of the number of vowels in each string in a new line. my code does the followiing:

**input**:

love

run

test

tryy

end

**output**:4

The desired output and input is below:

**input**:

love

run

test

tryy

end

**output**:

2

1

1

0

#include

using namespace std;

```
int main(){
    string name;
    int vowels=0, count=0;
    do
    {
        for(char i=0; i<name.length(); ++i)
        {
            if(name[i]=='a' || name[i]=='A' 
            || name[i]=='e' || name[i]=='E' 
            || name[i]=='i' || name[i]=='I' 
            || name[i]=='o' || name[i]=='O' 
            || name[i]=='u' || name[i]=='U')
            {
                vowels=vowels+1;
            }
            count+=count+1;
        }
    }
    while(cin >> name, name!="end"); 
    cout << vowels;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the strings are in new lines, and output must also be in different lines

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How can i change the code to give the desired output. mine gives the sum of all the vowels in all the strings, instead of the number of vowels in each string in a new line.

Comment: update your question, it doesn't mention what your issue is

Answer (score 0):

```
while(cin>>name && name!="end")
{
    int vowels = 0;
    for(auto i: name)
    {
        if(i=='a' || i=='A' 
            || i=='e' || i=='E' 
            || i=='i' || i=='I' 
            || i=='o' || i=='O' 
            || i=='u' || i=='U')
            {
                vowels++;
            }
            
            
    }
   cout<<name<<" "<<vowels<<'\n';
```

// prints the string and no of vowels in it.
}

Comment: Thank you, although it does not necessarily give the desired output. this is what i get when i test, not sure if that was the intention? test
test 0
test 1
test 1
test 1

no
no 0
no 1
pppp
pppp 0
pppp 0
pppp 0
pppp 0
end

Comment: oh sorry, my bad. cout was supposed to be outside for loop

Comment: I've updated the code, now it should give the desired output.

Comment: Thank you. How would i make sure that all the output is only shown after all inputs are inserted. as in input all my words, then only after get the number of vowels for each word.

Comment: One way you can do that is, instead of immedeately printing, you can store strings and their vowelCounts in two different vectors or a vector of pai<string,int> and then iterate the vector and print later

Comment: I tried using array lists, but struggling a bit on it.